# Force a program to run without admin privileges?

Tags: .net, manifest, privileges, administrator

I have a .net program that requests admin privileges by default whenever I try to run it. I don't know of any reason it NEEDS these privileges in my specific case, so I simply suspect lazy programming behind it (enforcing admin acces just in case it might eventually need it).

Is there any way I can force it to not try to elevate and run with the regular access rights? E.g. by modifying the embedded manifest or through some programmatic ways?

Running a regular app as administrator is pretty trivial, but is the reverse even possible?

**Update:**
I only have access to the compiled .exe, not to the source code or original manifest file. I've had a look at the embedded manifest of the .exe through [ManifestView](http://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/archive/2007/07/10/manifest-view-1-0.aspx) by Kenny Kerr and it definitely requests admin privileges as it includes the following:

```
<requestedPrivileges>
    <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" />
</requestedPrivileges>
```

Is there any way to change the manifest of a compiled .exe assembly? E.g. any tool around to do that or info about how to do that programmatically?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784692/how-to-avoid-user-account-control-or-run-windows-application-in-win7-always-in-a

Comment: @Jason: That appears to be the opposite of what's being asked for here.

Comment: @cHao: But it gives insight into the possible changes to the manifest that might be required, to reverse it.

Comment: The problem is I don't have access to the app's source code or manifest, only to the compiled .exe assembly. So how do I modify the manifest of a compiled .exe?

Comment: As the first step use Regmon and Filemon to determine to what registry keys and files / folders the program wants to get access

Comment: Get JustCode or Reflector decomplie and recompile :)

Comment: @Flot2011: that still doesn't help me with running the app as a standard user :(

Comment: Sudo for Windows (sudowin) allows authorized users to launch processes with elevated privileges using their own passphrase. Unlike the runas command, Sudo for Windows preserves the user's profile and ownership of created objects. http://sourceforge.net/projects/sudowin/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to create a small C# app to modify the embedded manifest so it wouldn't request admin privileges. This is the solution I finally came up with, making a bunch of Win32 calls to extract the manifest and replace an existing manifest. It's already long enough, so I omitted the part where I actually modify the manifest (just some basic XML operations).

There are two static methods here: **LoadManifestResource**, which loads the string representation of the embedded manifest of an executable and **SaveManifestResource**, which saves the string representation of a manifest resource in the specified executable, overwriting the old one.

This is a quick and dirty solution which worked just fine for me, but might very well not work in every case.

```
public static class Library
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr LoadLibraryEx(string lpFileName, IntPtr hReservedNull, LoadLibraryFlags dwFlags);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr FindResource(IntPtr hModule, int lpName, int lpType);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr LoadResource(IntPtr hModule, IntPtr hResInfo);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr LockResource(IntPtr hResData);

    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "SizeofResource", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern uint SizeofResource(IntPtr hModule, IntPtr hResource);

    [System.Flags]
    enum LoadLibraryFlags : uint
    {
        DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES = 0x00000001,
        LOAD_IGNORE_CODE_AUTHZ_LEVEL = 0x00000010,
        LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE = 0x00000002,
        LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE_EXCLUSIVE = 0x00000040,
        LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE = 0x00000020,
        LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH = 0x00000008
    }

    public static unsafe string LoadManifestResource(string fileName)
    {
        // load library to retrieve manifest from
        var libraryHandle = LoadLibraryEx(fileName, IntPtr.Zero, LoadLibraryFlags.LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE);
        if (libraryHandle.ToInt32() == 0)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(), "couldn't load library");
        }
        try
        {
            // find manifest
            var resource = FindResource(libraryHandle, 1, 24);
            if (resource.ToInt32() == 0)
            {
                throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(), "couldn't find manifest resource");
            }

            // load manifest
            var loadedManifest = LoadResource(libraryHandle, resource);
            if (loadedManifest.ToInt32() == 0)
            {
                throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(), "couldn't load manifest resource");
            }

            // lock manifest
            var lockedManifest = LockResource(loadedManifest);
            if (lockedManifest.ToInt32() == 0)
            {
                throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(), "couldn't lock manifest resource");
            }

            // calculate size of manifest, copy to byte array and convert to string
            int manifestSize = (int)SizeofResource(libraryHandle, resource);

            byte[] data = new byte[manifestSize];
            Marshal.Copy(lockedManifest, data, 0, manifestSize);
            var manifest = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);

            return manifest;
        }
        finally
        {
            FreeLibrary(libraryHandle);
        }
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr BeginUpdateResource(string pFileName,
       [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]bool bDeleteExistingResources);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool UpdateResource(IntPtr hUpdate, string lpType, string lpName, ushort wLanguage, IntPtr lpData, uint cbData);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool UpdateResource(IntPtr hUpdate, int lpType, int lpName, ushort wLanguage, IntPtr lpData, uint cbData);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool EndUpdateResource(IntPtr hUpdate, bool fDiscard);

    public static unsafe void SaveManifestResource(string file, string manifest)
    {
        var hUpdate = BeginUpdateResource(file, false);

        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(manifest);
        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bytes.Length);
        try
        {
            Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, ptr, bytes.Length);

            if (!UpdateResource(hUpdate, 24, 1, 0, ptr, (uint)bytes.Length))
            {
                throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            }

            if (!EndUpdateResource(hUpdate, false))
            {
                throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have any code in the app that requires Admini privileges, i believe you wont be able to run the app.

Some code/apis are flagged to require certain privileges. So I dont believe you can get passed that :/

The only solution I would see, is separate the incriminated code into a module that you might load or not load. So that would enable you to have to run both versions, while maintaining the "same" product.

Comment: Sorry, should have clarified that earlier in the question: I don't have access to the source code, so can't really move that code to a separate module at all. Well, maybe through de- and recompiling but I'd rather not go there if it can be avoided.