# Disabling UAC programmatically - Change doesn't take effect?

Tags: c#, registry, admin, uac

I created a C# application that changes the "EnableLUA" key to 0,
the application is run with admin rights, and no errors pop up:

```
//Runs with admin rights
try 
{
RegistryKey key = 
Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System", true);
            key.SetValue("EnableLUA", "0");
            key.Close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + e);
}
```

The registry key indeed gets changed from 1 to 0, but even after restarting the computer, 
UAC is still enabled. Then when I go to Control Panel > User Account Control, the slider is turned all the way down. When pressing "Save" (and not having modified anything), UAC suddenly seems to be disabled.

Would this be a bug of some sort or just a weird kind of security? Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UAC can't be disabled programatically, it's designed to prevent such an act.  The whole point to UAC was to make it impossible for anything other than user interaction to bypass/disable it.

Sure, you can set the registry key to 0, and you can see the slider moved, but unless the user is actually the one causing that action (commiting it with OK) it won't update.

UAC operates at a low level of the OS, your code would have to be running in the kernel level to be able to disable UAC, running as admin isn't enough.  And Execute Disable Bit in modern bios's will prevent your code from injecting into the kernel with any kind of method (e.g. buffer overflows)

A better solution would be to detect if UAC is enabled and direct the user on how to turn it off.

Unless you want to do something really wacky, like programatically open the screen to disable uac and simulate mouse input to click the slider down to none and click ok.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that with admin rights this should be possible, but it appears not. I could open the UAC window, press tab two times and then press enter, but that would be very ugly. I will just notify the user.

Comment: You can configure an application to always run elevated with the compatibility tab on the exe's properties page.  You can also create a short cut that runs your application elevated.

e.g. "elevate myprogramsexe.exe"

If you give your program some kind of installer, or design it with a bootstrap exe that launches the real exe you can go that route.  The user will get a popup from UAC, but once accepted and ran they won't get anymore because it's running elevated.

Comment: .@ Ryios Thanks for commenting, but even when ran elevated, the application will bring up the UAC prompt at the next startup of the application. I wanted to know if it was possible to disable UAC programmatically with admin rights, which appears not possible.

Comment: Group Policies can disable UAC remotely, and can probably be set programmatically by a domain administrator.

Comment: Yeah, you can do it with group policies, but that's because you are on a domain that is trusted to have that power.  The average home user isn't on a domain.  Also in contexts where home users vpn in to work on their own machines, it wouldn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

This version works:

Reference:

```
using System.Management.Automation;
```

Code:

```
var script = PowerShell.Create();
script.AddScript("Set-ItemProperty \"HKLM:\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\System\" -Name \"ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin\" -Value \"0\" ");
script.Invoke();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the 32bit DWORD to a string value and therefore it **doesn't work**

It is **absolutley possible** to disable uac if you just specify the valuekind to a dword like this

```
key.SetValue("EnableLUA", "0", RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

*note that you also need to run program as administrator for the program to acces hklm (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) in regedit*

*Tested in windows 10 and it works, i do not know if it works in win7 but let me know if it does*

Answer (score 0):

Despite the UAC warning that it only works after OK, this was not the behavior, windows assumed the change and disabled UAC, I tested it and it was the lack of DWORD in WINDOWS 10

Answer (score -1):

**You can simply Remove the UAC prompt by writing two line of code,**

```
string UAC_key = @"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System";
Registry.SetValue(UAC_key, "EnableLUA", 0);`
```

Comment: Sorry - I normally don't comment on things negatively, but is this a joke?  It's literally what the original poster put in his question and just said will not work.

Comment: had to down vote as changing the value will not do anything as pointed out in the correct answer.