# C# admin rights with credentials

Tags: c#, admin, uac

after reading all topic about C# runas issues, i still can't find my solution.

My problem here is simple, i'm on a user session with no rights and i want to execute an exe as Admin.

I tried many things like:

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "isauq.exe",
    UserName = "user",
    Domain = "",
    Password = pass,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true
};
Process.Start(psi);
```

With the password as an AppendChild for each characters.
I have the admin credentials but seems like the UAC prompt is still popping up

Is there any solutions in C# or Bat ? Or any solution to automate the user entries in UAC prompt ?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disabling UAC programmatically - Change doesn't take effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26238779/disabling-uac-programmatically-change-doesnt-take-effect)

Comment: Thanks Markus, but no, in fact i would like to get a long-term solution for this issue...

Comment: I'm not sure my link worked correctly. I wanted to point you to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26239002/2921691) that states _UAC can't be disabled programatically, it's designed to prevent such an act. The whole point to UAC was to make it impossible for anything other than user interaction to bypass/disable it._

Comment: Yes i see, so may i conclude with a 'No' ? There is no way to get admin rights from a simple user session ?

Comment: Well I am no expert on that topic but is it possible for you to do some parametrization on the server? And I would like to add here that in my opinion the problem is not, that you are not getting admin rights but that the UAC pop up is in your way, right?

Comment: If you are asking if you can automatically elevate an application to run as administrator from a non-elevated session without the system prompting to ask for credentials: The answer is "no." (Think about if this were possible: All malware would take advantage of this security hole!)

Comment: Of course ! I'm aware of security issues, but these admin rights are needed to updates things as Services, installing them or turning off them...

Comment: I refer the honorable gentleman to my previous reply posted on 13 April.

Comment: Oh i didn't saw that, this is embedded computer, not linked to a server but yeah we have the whole control of it. The main goal is to have a independant user but for now i can modify whatever i want to